# Ruby csv: no rows found in single column import file

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm happily using the Ruby 1.9.3 CSV library to import CSV files ([csv/rdoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html))

But when the file has only a single column, no data rows are found, even though it can find the header field.

```
require 'csv'
csv = CSV.new(File.open(import_dir + "#{table}.csv"), :headers => true, :col_sep => ';')
csv.each do |row|
```

each doesn't return any elements for a single column file. This code is working fine for all other files

The file is simply:

```
name
sample account
```

The code finds the header "name" but sees no data rows. I tried quoting the value and adding extra rows. If I add a second column before or after, the data rows can be seen.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works here, I get one row object `#<CSV::Row "name":"sample account">`.

Comment: Is your file delimited with semi colons? It looks like in the options hash you have `:col_sep => ';'`

Comment: Yes, semi colon delimeters. I've just hit the same problem again. It's specifically in the case of a single column row (the second row being blank, with or without the trailing delimeter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by a bug in the app code, nothing to do with the ruby CSV library